# Issues calling a page method from javascript

Tags: ajax, webforms, pagemethods

I haven't used this before so I'm probably missing something, is this even possible?

```
 function myFunc(obj) {
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "CMSWebParts_PSS_Test.aspx/CallMe",
                data: obj,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

And the .cs:

```
    public partial class CMSWebParts_PSS_Test : CMSAbstractWebPart
    { ...
    [WebMethod]
        public static string CallMe(string data)
        {
           return card;
        }...
    }
```

I keep getting 404.
Tried using PageMethods but still getting the same result.

Comment: Why does the code-behind page not inherit from `: System.Web.UI.Page`?

Answer (score 0):

Make your data a string

```
data: JSON.stringify(obj),
```

`msg` is a wrapper. The requested data is put into a property -> d

```
success: function (msg) {
    alert(msg.d):
}
```

Also, call your function `myFunc` *or* use `$(document).ready`.

---

Update: try moving the success part outside of the initial call, change the name to 'done'.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "CMSWebParts_PSS_Test.aspx/CallMe",
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"        
}).done(function (msg) {
    alert(msg.d);
)}.fail(function() {
   //
});
```

Comment: It still can't find the CallMe method, keep getting 404.

Comment: Update your question to show exactly what you have now and include 'Updated' somewhere.